# Rtk query always returns cached data. InvalidatesTags not doing anything

Tags: react-native, caching, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Can somebody tell me why I still get the cached data after I invalidate the getUser query?

**api.ts:**

```
export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: REACT_APP_API_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
      const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.token;
      if (token) {
        headers.set('Authorization', token);
      }
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  tagTypes: [
    'UserGet',
    'UserPost',
  ],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

**userGetApi.ts:**

```
const userGetApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUserData: builder.query<UserData, void>({
      query: () => '/users/me',
      providesTags: ['UserGet'],
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: true,
});
export const { useGetUserDataQuery } = userGetApi;
```

**userPostApi.ts:**

```
const userPostApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    saveUser: builder.mutation<void, OnboardingEntry>({
      query: (userEntries) => {
        const formData = Object.keys(userEntries).reduce((formData, key) => {
          formData.append(key, userEntries[key].toString());
          return formData;
        }, new FormData());
        return {
          url: '/users/update',
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
        };
      },
      invalidatesTags: ['UserGet'],
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: true,
});

export const { useSaveUserMutation } = userPostApi;
```

**The 2 hooks I call:**

```
const { data: { data } = {}, isLoading, isError, isSuccess } = useGetUserDataQuery();
const [saveUser, { isLoading: postIsLoading, isSuccess: postIsSuccess }] = useSaveUserMutation();
```

After calling saveUser(...), I get redirected to another page. When I revisit the page, I expect to see the updated user data from useGetUserDataQuery(), but I see the previous data. Even when I close and reopen the app, I still get the old data!

So what am I doing wrong here? I'm using 'ProvidesTags' & 'InvalidatesTags' as stated in the docs.

Comment: That does look okay. Have you taken a look into the Redux Devtools? You should see if something is refetching there or not.

Comment: In the redux devtools an action type "api/subscriptions/unsubscribeQueryResult" is executed with payload 'queryCacheKey:"getUserData(undefined)"', after the mutation.
When revisiting, action type "api/executeQuery/rejected" is executed with error "Aborted due to condition callback returning false." So no refetch happened. I don't understand

Comment: which version of Redux Toolkit are you importing createApi from?

Comment: import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
& In package.json -> @reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1"

Comment: I guess at this point you'd have to provide a CodeSandbox. I'm sorry.

Comment: Update: When calling refetch() from useGetUserDataQuery(), I still receive cached data

Comment: Do you maybe have multiple stores or something? As I said: you really need to provide a CodeSandbox, everything else is crystal ball debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after days of pure frustration I found the solution: **Api headers**.

```
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: REACT_APP_API_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
      headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      headers.set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
      headers.set('Expires', '0');

      const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.token;
      if (token) {
        headers.set('Authorization', token);
      }
      return headers;
    },
  }),
```

Hopefully this answer will help others as well