# RTK Query not Invalidating Data When App is Hosted, but works on Localhost

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I am working on this app that is so data intensive. I have implemented RTK Query and my issue is with the invalidation of tags after mutation changes via API call. It works well on localhost where all the tags are invalidated as needed, but when I host the app, no invalidation happens even after an API call is successful and data has been changed on the server. Hard-refreshing the app doesn't help, until I have to clear the browser cache for the changes to reflect on the UI. I also notice that the network API calls are being fired, but updating the stale data on the cache does not take place. I will add here all the necessary code that may help to debug this issue.

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from '../api/apiSlice';
import authReducer from "./auth/authSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
        auth: authReducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware)
});
```

apiSlice.js

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { Mutex } from 'async-mutex';
import { logout, setCredentials } from '../features/auth/authSlice';
import { baseUrlDev, baseUrlPro } from './baseUrl';

const baseURL =
    window.location.hostname.includes("dev") || window.location.hostname.includes("localhost")
        ? baseUrlDev
        : baseUrlPro;

const mutex = new Mutex();

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: baseURL,
    credentials: 'include',
    timeout: 15000,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState}) => {
        const token = getState().auth.token || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"))?.accessToken;
        if (token) {
            headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
        }
        return headers;
    }
});

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    await mutex.waitForUnlock();
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)

    if (result?.error?.originalStatus === 403) {
        if (!mutex.isLocked()) {
            const release = await mutex.acquire();

            try {
                console.log('sending refresh token');
                // send refresh token to get a new access token
                const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/auth/refresh', api, extraOptions);
                // console.log(refreshResult);

                if(refreshResult?.data) {
                    const email = api.getState().auth.email || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"))?.email;
                    const role = api.getState().auth.role || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"))?.role;
                    const name = api.getState().auth.name || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"))?.name;
                    // store the new token
                    api.dispatch(setCredentials({ 
                        accessToken: refreshResult.data.accessToken, 
                        email, 
                        role, 
                        name,
                        branch: refreshResult.data.branch, 
                        company: refreshResult.data.company
                    }));
                    // retry the original query with new access token
                    result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
                } else {
                    await baseQuery('/auth/logout', api, extraOptions);
                    api.dispatch(logout());
                }
            } finally {
                release();
            }
        } else {
            await mutex.waitForUnlock();
            result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    tagTypes: [
        'Branch', 'Company', 'Customer', 'Driver', 'Parcel', 'ParcelTransaction', 
        'ParcelType', 'Staff', 'Town', 'TransactionChannel', 'User', 'VehicleOwner', 
        'Vehicle', 'VehicleType'
    ],
    refetchOnMountOrArgChange: 5,
    refetchOnFocus: true,
    endpoints: builder => ({})
})
```

I also set the `refetchOnFocus` to be true on the baseQuery but it doesn't work at all. I was thinking this would help, but the cache is persistent, even if the system remains dominant for more than 30 mins. I mean it should even refetch data on the minimum, but it continues to use the stale cache data.

parcelSlice.js

```
import { createSelector, createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from '../../api/apiSlice';

const SLICE_URL = '/parcels';

const parcelsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
    sortComparer: (a, b) => b.parcelCode.localeCompare(a.parcelCode)
})

const initialState = parcelsAdapter.getInitialState()

export const parcelApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getParcels: builder.query({
            query: () => `${SLICE_URL}`,
            transformResponse: responseData => {
                return parcelsAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData)
            },
            providesTags: (result, error, id) => ['Parcel', 'ParcelTransaction']
        }),
        getParcel: builder.query({
            query: (id) => `${SLICE_URL}/${id}`,
            providesTags: (result, error, id) => ['Parcel', 'ParcelTransaction'],
        }),
        getParcelsAvailableForDispatch: builder.query({
            query: () => `${SLICE_URL}/available-for-dispatch`,
            providesTags: (result, error, id) => ['Parcel', 'ParcelTransaction'],
        }),
        getParcelsAssignedToVehicle: builder.query({
            query: (vehicleID) => `${SLICE_URL}/assigned-to-vehicle/?vehicleID=${vehicleID}`,
            providesTags: (result, error, id) => ['Parcel', 'ParcelTransaction'],
        }),
        getParcelsAwaitingRecipients: builder.query({
            query: () => `${SLICE_URL}/parcels-awaiting-recipients`,
            providesTags: (result, error, id) => ['Parcel', 'ParcelTransaction'],
        }),
        addParcel: builder.mutation({
            query: parcelData => ({
                url: `${SLICE_URL}`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: {
                    ...parcelData
                }
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Parcel', 'ParcelTransaction']
        }),
        issueParcel: builder.mutation({
            query: parcelID => ({
                url: `${SLICE_URL}/issue-parcel/${parcelID}`,
                method: 'PATCH',
                body: {
                    id: parcelID
                }
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Parcel', 'ParcelTransaction']
        }),
        updateParcel: builder.mutation({
            query: ({id, parcelData}) => ({
                url: `${SLICE_URL}/${id}`,
                method: 'PATCH',
                body: {
                    ...parcelData
                }
            }),
            invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
                { type: 'Parcel', id: arg.id }
            ]
        }),
    })
});

export const {
    useGetParcelsQuery,
    useGetParcelQuery,
    useGetParcelsAvailableForDispatchQuery,
    useGetParcelsAssignedToVehicleQuery,
    useGetParcelsAwaitingRecipientsQuery,
    useAddParcelMutation,
    useIssueParcelMutation,
    useUpdateParcelMutation,
} = parcelApiSlice;

// returns the query result object
export const selectParcelsResult = parcelApiSlice.endpoints.getParcels.select();

// Creates memoized selector
const selectParcelsData = createSelector(
    selectParcelsResult,
    parcelsResult => parcelsResult.data // normalized state object with ids & entities
);

//getSelectors creates these selectors and we rename them with aliases using destructuring
export const {
    selectAll: selectAllParcels,
    selectById: selectParcelById,
    selectIds: selectParcelIds
    // Pass in a selector that returns the parcels slice of state
} = parcelsAdapter.getSelectors(state => selectParcelsData(state) ?? initialState)
```

An example use case is when I want to issue a parcel to a customer using the `issueParcel` mutation on the `parcelSlice`, the thing is, the current parcel status should change the status to delivered and update the UI by refetching data once the API mutation call has been made and the mutation is successful. However, this only happens in locahost, but does not happen when I host the app in the server. This is part of the code that I am using on the parcel's details component.

parcelDetails.jsx

```
const ParcelDetails = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const theme = useTheme();

    const { data: parcelDetails, isLoading, isError, error, refetch } = useGetParcelQuery(id);
    const [issueParcel] = useIssueParcelMutation()

    const authenticatedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"));

    const breadcrumbs = [
        { name: "Parcel", path: "/parcel" }, 
        { name: parcelDetails?.parcelCode }
    ];

    const staffName = parcelDetails?.staff?.ownuser?.firstName + " " + parcelDetails?.staff?.ownuser?.lastName;

    const handleIssueParcel = (parcelID) => {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure you want to issue this parcel?',
            html: '<p>ParcelCode: ' + parcelDetails.parcelCode + '</p> <br />',
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, issue Parcel!'
        }).then(async (result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                try {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "Issuing Parcel",
                        html: "Please wait..."
                    })
                    Swal.showLoading()
                    await issueParcel(parcelID);
                    refetch();
                    Swal.hideLoading()
                    Swal.fire(`parcel ${parcelDetails.parcelCode} issued successfully!`, '', 'success');
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            } else if (result.isDenied) {
                Swal.fire('Parcel not issued.', '', 'info');
            }
        })
    }

    return (<>Parcel Display UI</>)
}

export default ParcelDetails
```

I even tried to force `refetch()` of the data after every API call is successful, but this does not work when the app is hosted on the server.
I believe it is something small that I am missing out. I will appreciate your review and advice on the same.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by adding this to the `baseQuery`. Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72175487/rtk-query-always-returns-cached-data-invalidatestags-not-doing-anything) question that was facing a similar problem as mine.

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: baseURL,
    credentials: 'include',
    timeout: 15000,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState}) => {
        headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
        headers.set('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        headers.set('Expires', '0');

        const token = getState().auth.token || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticatedUser"))?.accessToken;
        if (token) {
            headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
        }
        return headers;
    }
});
```